# Setting realtime priority to a process

Tags: windows, cpu, process

I'm looking into getting max performance for a game, and I stumbled across the concept of realtime priority. Now, I understand what it does, and was wondering if there was any risk in setting the process' priority to realtime with a dual-core CPU, since for what I've gathered, realtime delegates only a core to that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These were BAD answers even 10 years ago. As long as you have multiple CPUs OR a single CPU with multiple cores, this only can be bad if the process you set to RT can use ALL CPUs/Cores. As long as there are free cores, there's absolutely no harm in setting something to RT. I've seen games to RT for a decade with no problems whatsoever

Comment: Interesting. How do you prevent a realtime process from using all cores?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set real-time priority as it is dangerous. If you set a CPU-intensive program to real-time, it will suck up your entire processor, leaving no cycles for anything else i.e mouse input, keyboard input and disk cache.

Comment: I have seen reports of people who have successfully run stuff in realtime (i.e. games) with responsive periferals though.

Answer (score 1):

With my experience, practically nothing should be set to `realtime`.. It will hang your PC (and then you may need to manually restart PC/LAPTOP, by pressing the shutdown button for 5 seconds). I think, it could be only given to process, that you know is going to be finished soon (and thus, you will make them finish sooner), but till that process finishes, you may have no control of PC.

That's just my opinion, more programmatically-aware answer will be appreciated.